# Laravel 8 - count repeated value by month for a period between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I am working with Laravel 8 and get stuck creating a custom query return  client data with number of visits by month for every client
first this is the tables structure

> clients table  has id and name, ....etc
>
> reports table has id , report_date and city, ...etc
>
> report_details  has id,report_id, client_id, ...etc

the relation between Report and report_details is one to one

I create a relation in Report model as following

```
public function reportDetails() {
    return $this->hasOne(reportDetails::class, 'report_id');
}
```

I want to execute a query between two dates for example between 01-01-2021 and 25-03-2021 generate a JSON array and every object has with following keys

> client_id, client_name, month, visits_count_by_month

I expect to get following result

```
[
    {
        "client_id": 2,
        "client_name": "John",
        "client_visits: [
            "Jan": 5,
            "Feb": 2,
            "March": 0
        ]
    },

    {
        "client_id": 5,
        "client_name": "Mark",
        "client_visits: [
            "Jan": 2,
            "Feb": 0,
            "March": 0
        ]
    }
]
```

I write the following query but I don't know how to customize it and link it with third table clients

```
$reports = Report::whereBetween('report_date', [$start_date, $end_date])->get();
```

Comment: you can't achieve that with in single query i need to make a php script with loops and conditions as per your requirement to get each month of user visit count, by from, to date in between months.

Comment: thanks for reply. yes I understand your meaning but I am looking if there is some thing easer in Laravel